# Django API call not rendering in templates

Tags: django, django-templates

i am making an API call to get weather, but i am not able to loop through the results in template also note that i am able to print the result in terminal

Here is my code:

```
def index(request):
    url = 'http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key={}&q={}&aqi=no'
    api_key = 'MY_KEY'

    # print(response.text)

    cities = City.objects.all()
    weather_data = []

    for city in cities:
        response = requests.get(url.format(api_key, city)).json()
        city_weather = {
            'city': city.name,
            'temperature': response['current']['temp_c'],
            'description': response['current']['condition']['text'],
            'icon': response['current']['condition']['icon'],
        }
        weather_data.append(city_weather)

    print(weather_data)
    context = {
        'weather_data': city_weather
    }
    return render(request, 'weather_app/index.html', context)
```

Here is my template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {% for city_weather in weather_data %}
                {{city_weather.temperature}}
        {% endfor %}
    </body>
    </html>
```

This is the result i get in terminal

```
[{'city': 'Cairo', 'temperature': 19.0, 'description': 'Partly cloudy'}, {'city': 'Paris', 'temperature': 7.0, 'description': 'Partly cloudy'}, {'city': 'Tokyo', 'temperature': 13.8, 'description': 'Patchy rain possible'}]
```

Not sure why i am not able to pass the result to template, is there something i am missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing the wrong variable into your context here:

```
context = {
  'weather_data': city_weather
}
```

It should probably be `'weather_data': weather_data`.

Comment: It happens to everyone.